Substituting lighter gauge wire for a heavy gauge wire
Would two 10 AWG wires replace one 8 AWG? I am setting up a 2-pole 50
amp breaker.

In general should be working. But keep in mind that if one of the wires breaks, all the current will go through the other one, potentially burning it or even causing fire (that depends on the actual current and wire specifications of course).

Every three AWG sizes means twice the cross-sectional area.  So 2 10 AWG wires have more current carrying capability than a single 8 AWG.

Check with DIY since this is definitely an electrical code question (assuming this is for your house).

Ask on DIY why you shouldn't do this.

It would, as total area of two 10 AWG wires is more than area of single 8 AWG wire.
But you can't do it, as it would be a safety hazard and likely make the installation illegal if it is against your local electrical code, rules and legislation, and you will likely be legally responsible for any problems made by your installtion.

Thanks for that. I understand why it works but is not allowed by code.
